# Get Journey ID of SMS send using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to get the journey ID from SMS send so I created a code that should get the SendJobId

```
set @jobid = AttributeValue('SendJobID')
```

However I cannot retrieve any values. I was hoping to get the SendJobID to use it  to get the journeyID using the code below:

```
IF NOT (empty(@jobid)) THEN
set @tsdid = Lookup("_Job", "TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID", "JobID", @jobid)
set @version_id = Lookup("_JourneyActivity", "VersionID", "JourneyActivityObjectID", @tsdid)
set @journey_id = Lookup("_Journey", "JourneyID", "VersionID", @version_id)
set @journeyName = Lookup("_Journey", "JourneyName", "VersionID", @version_id)
set @campaignID = @journey_id
ENDIF
```

My question is can I get the SendJobId using AttributeValue syntax? If yes, what might be the cause that I only get a null value.

Comment: _job data view is for email and not sms

Comment: @EazyE thanks for pointing that out, would you know what approach can I use to get the journey Id from journey SMS send?

Answer (score 0):

Try to query _smsmessagetracking data view, some of the available fields are: CampaignID, ConversationID, CodeID.